# about spin lock

Tags: c++, locking

i have some questions in boost spinlock code :

```
class spinlock
{
public:
    spinlock()
        : v_(0)
    {
    }

    bool try_lock()
    {
        long r = InterlockedExchange(&v_, 1);
        _ReadWriteBarrier();        // 1. what this mean            
        return r == 0;
    }

    void lock()
    {
        for (unsigned k = 0; !try_lock(); ++k)
        {
            yield(k);
        }
    }

    void unlock()
    {

        _ReadWriteBarrier();                      
        *const_cast<long volatile*>(&v_) = 0;  
        // 2. Why don't need to use InterlockedExchange(&v_, 0);
    }

private:
    long v_;
};
```

Comment: Well, unlocking is unconditional...

Comment: @KerrekSB Also, a priori, if you're calling `unlock`, you have the lock, and `v_` can only be `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A ReadWriteBarrier() is a "memory barrier" (in this case for both reads and writes), a special instruction to the processor to ensure that any instructions resulting in memory operations have completed (`load` & `store` operations - or in for example x86 processors, any opertion which has a memory operand at either side). In this particular case, to make sure that the InterlockedExchange(&v_,1) has completed before we continue.
2. Because an `InterlockedExchange` would be less efficient (takes more interaction with any other cores in the machine to ensure all other processor cores have 'let go' of the value - which makes no sense, since most  likely (in correctly working code) we only `unlock` if we actually hold the lock, so no other processor will have a different value cached than what we're writing over anyway), and a `volatile` write to the memory will be just as good.

Comment: Since you mention x86 -- isn't x86 strongly ordered, so the memory barrier is implicit? I believe the code mainly acts as a *compiler* barrier on x86, with no additional machine code.

Comment: It is not clear to me if it actually results in an instruction or not: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f20w0x5e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Whether a `volitile` write will work depends on the compiler.  It won't work with g++, for example, nor with some versions of VC++.  And of course, unless the code does a `yield`, the other thread may not be able to read it even if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The barriers are there to ensure memory synchronization; without
them, different threads may see modifications of memory in
different orders.

And the `InterlockedExchange` isn't necessary in the second case
because we're not interested in the previous value.  The role of
`InterlockedExchange` is doubtlessly to set the value and return
the previous value.  (And why `v_` would be `long`, when it can
only take values `0` and `1`, is beyond me.)

Comment: What if `InterlockedExchange` only exists for `long`s?

Comment: Then the author of the library isn't very good.  In fact, I would expect the contrary: `InterlockedExchange` needs a type which it can access atomically.  On a lot of platforms I've worked on, `long` cannot be accessed atomically.  (On some, nothing larger than `char` could be accessed atomically.)

Comment: This is Windows, right? I don't know it very well, but I assume they would have chosen a type (probably called `LONG` or `ZKLNGSZINT` or something handy) that is atomic.

Comment: Is it Windows?  If it's platform specific code, you could be right (although seriously, for a variable that can only take values 0 and 1, and has to be atomic, would _you_ chose anything other than `char` or `unsigned char`?).

Comment: [It would seem so.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683590(v=vs.85).aspx). So I don't think you have a choice in that matter: The only function you can use requires a machine word operand... (you're passing a pointer!).

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues with atomic access to variables. First, ensuring that there is no thread switch in the middle of reading or writing a value; if this happens it's called "tearing"; the second thread can see a partly written value, which will usually be nonsensical. Second, ensuring that all processors see the change that is being made with a write, or that the processor reading a value sees any previous changes to that value; this is called "cache coherency". Third, ensuring that the **compiler** doesn't move code across the read or write; this is called "code motion". `InterlockedExchange` does the first two; although the MSDN documentation is rather muddled, `_ReadWriteBarrier` does the third, and possibly the second.